# How to implement emotion or expression detection in react native

Tags: react-native, tensorflow, react-hooks, face-detection

I have can anyone help me with emotion detection in React native I am getting the face detected but having problem in emotion detection. How to detect emotion in react native
To detect emotion and give details with face
`import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Alert } from 'react-native'; import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'; import { RNCamera } from 'react-native-camera'; import Orientation from 'react-native-orientation-locker'; import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';` 
`const PendingView = () => (
<View
style={{
flex: 1,
backgroundColor: 'lightgreen',
justifyContent: 'center',
alignItems: 'center',
}}
>
<Text style={{ color: '#ffffff' }}>Waiting

);
const EmotionModel = async () => {
const model = await tf.loadGraphModel(
'./src/modals/face_expression_model-shard1', // Path to the model.json file
);

```
return model;
 };`


`const App = () => {
const [faces, setFaces] = useState([]);
const [emotionModel, setEmotionModel] = useState(null);


 const handleFacesDetected = (response) => {
 if (response.faces.length > 0) {
 // Only set the first detected face in the array
  setFaces([response.faces[0]]);
   } else {
 setFaces([]);
 }
 };
 useEffect(() => {
 let isMounted = true;

 EmotionModel()
.then((model) => {
 if (isMounted) {
   setEmotionModel(model);
 }
 })
.catch((error) => {
 console.error('Error loading the emotion detection model:', error);
 // Handle the error as needed (e.g., show an error message to the user)
 });

return () => {
isMounted = false;
if (emotionModel) {
 emotionModel.dispose(); // Dispose of the model to release resources
 }
 };
 }, []);`


      ` const renderFaceBorders = () => {
     `   return faces.map((face, index) => (
            <View
            key={index}
            style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            borderColor: 'green',
            borderWidth: 2,
            left: face.bounds.origin.x,
            top: face.bounds.origin.y,
            width: face.bounds.size.width,
            height: face.bounds.size.height,
            }}
        />
        ));
        };

        const takePicture = async (camera) => {
        if (!emotionModel) return;


        const options = { quality: 0.5, base64: true };
        const data = await camera.takePictureAsync(options);
        console.log(data.uri);
        const imageTensor = tf.browser.fromPixels({ uri: data.uri });
        const resizedImageTensor = tf.image.resizeBilinear(imageTensor, [224, 224]);
        const batchedImageTensor = resizedImageTensor.expandDims(0).div(255.0);
        const predictions = await emotionModel.predict(batchedImageTensor).data();
        // Find the emotion with the highest probability
        const maxEmotionIndex = predictions.indexOf(Math.max(...predictions));
        const emotions = ["Angry", "Disgust", "Fear", "Happy", "Sad", "Surprise", "Neutral"];
        const detectedEmotion = emotions[maxEmotionIndex];

        Alert.alert('Detected Emotion', `Emotion: ${detectedEmotion}`);
        if (faces.length === 0) {
        // Show an alert if no faces are detected
        Alert.alert('No Face Detected', 'Please try again with a face in the frame.');
        } 

        };
        useEffect(() => {
        Orientation.lockToPortrait();
        return () => {
        // Unlock the orientation when the screen is unmounted
        Orientation.unlockAllOrientations();
        };
        }, []);`

                return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                <RNCamera
                    style={styles.preview}
                    type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.front}
                    faceDetectionMode={RNCamera.Constants.FaceDetection.Mode.fast}
                    onFacesDetected={handleFacesDetected}
                >
                    {({ camera, status }) => {
                    if (status !== 'READY') return <PendingView />;
                    return (
                        <View style={{ flex: 0, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => takePicture(camera)} style={styles.capture}>

                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    );
                    }}
                </RNCamera>
                {renderFaceBorders()}
                </View>
                );
                };

                export default App;`
```